# removing all trailing whitespaces

Tags: regex, perl

I want to remove all trailing white spaces from my .rb file. Also I want to remove all trailing ^M characters. This is what I have got. Does it look okay?

```
find . -name '*.rb' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/ +$//'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a regex for trailing whitespace use the `\s` meta character which stands for all whitespace characters

```
find . -name '*.rb' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\s+$//'
```

If you want to maintain a line break then change the replacement term to something like

```
find . -name '*.rb' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\s+$/\n/'
```

or

```
find . -name '*.rb' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\s+$/\r\n/'
```

This will however mean that the lines now have trailing whitespace again.

Comment: running that command is reducing all 100 lines into a single line. That's not good.

Comment: Try `'s/\s+$//m'` for multiline mode

Comment: You said remove all trailing white space, that include the final '\n' or '\r' so yes you would get a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I think find + sed will do the job for you:

```
find . -name '*.rb' -exec sed -i.bak 's/\s*$//' {} \;
```

On **Mac** use this command since `\s` (a perl extension) is not recognized on Mac's sed:

```
find . -name '*.rb' -exec sed -i.bak 's/[ ^I^M]*$//' {} \;
```

`-i` is for inline editing
`-i.bak` is for keeping a backup of original with .bak extension.

Comment: @Nick Vanderbilt: Above command will remove all trailing `^M` characters as well while preserving your blank lines as is.

Comment: That's awesome. and it is working. Thank you. How do I tell it to do the same for .js, .erb, .txt and .css.

Comment: your script is removing 's' in the end. -    @households = @user.households
+    @households = @user.household

Comment: You can use find like this: `find . \( -name '*.rb' -or -name '*.js' -or -name '*.css' -or -name '*.txt' \) -exec sed -i.bak 's/\s*$//' {} \;` for that

Comment: It is not removing letter `s`, it is just removing trailing `\s` which means any whitespace character.

Comment: It is actually removing the letter. See the diff I posted. It changed "households" to "household".

Comment: @Nick Vanderbilt: I have tested with your inputs as well few times and other than trailing spaces nothing else gets removed. `\s` is not supposed to remove anything but whitespace anyway. may I know on what platform you are trying this. Can you put your sample file as well here.

Comment: I am on mac. Also following line is failing. notice I do not want .bak file. find . -name '*.rb' -exec sed -i 's/\s*$//' {} \;

Comment: Ah Mac's sed doesn't know about `\s` which is a perl extension. Try this on Mac: `find . -name '*.rb' -exec sed -i.bak 's/[ \t^M]*$//' {} \;` I have tested this on my Mac and worked fine. `^M` is entered by `ctrl-v-m` keys together. Also it seems if you provide `-i` then you have to provide some extension on Mac otherwise it gives error.

Comment: Ah even `\t` is an issue on Mac :( try sed 's/[      ^M]*$//' and enter tab by pressing `ctrl-v-i` together.